# Why is Java VirtualBox doesn't have a 64bit OS version selector?

Tags: window

I want to install window 10 on window 8.1(64 bit) host but java virtual box didn't have 64 bit option. Mean if i select windows in type then it shows only 32 versions of window but i need 64 bit version here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://windows7bugs.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/install-windows-10-technical-preview-on-oracle-java-virtualbox/

I've mentioned about removing Hyper-V in order to install 64Bit OS. Hope it helps you :)